# swagger document and swag client code for DDD enums in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, swagger, nswag

I have some custom enumeration types based on DDD classes as shown ghere: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types

I am using asp.net 5, and when I generate the client code using nswag or view the swagger document, it emits the enum classes as complex types instead of list of literal enum names.

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(options =>
        {
            options.GenerateEnumMappingDescription = true;
            var obj = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
            obj.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            obj.Converters.Add(new Converters.NewtonsoftEnumerationJsonConverter());
            options.SerializerSettings = obj;
            options.SchemaProcessors.Add(new EnumerationSchemaProcessor());
            options.OperationProcessors.Add(new EnumerationOperationProcessor());
            options.SchemaGenerator = new EnumerationOpenApiSchemaGenerator(options);
            options.ReflectionService = new CustomReflectionService();
            options.TypeNameGenerator = new TypeNameGenerator();
            options.SchemaNameGenerator = new SchemaNameGenerator();
        });
```

The complex enum classes has properties: int Id, string Name

I am able to submit the Name or Id via the api endpoints (by using the modelbinder), its only the swagger documentation that is not working correctly

Thanks

Comment: I found this link quite useful in this regard: https://ankitvijay.net/2020/07/12/enumeration-class-nswag/